# add a new column in pyspark dataframe based on matching values from a list

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am looking for help with pyspark on adding a new column with matching list values.

I have a list of values with variable **unique_ids**

```
[Row(card_id=1), Row(card_id=2)]
```

for each value in the list, if the list value matches column value, then count the number of rows that matches the value and add then create a new column with count value

this is how I am getting the list

```
unique_ids = data.select('card_id').distinct().collect()
```

example df

| card_id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |

required dataframe

| card_id | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 |

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function `count`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

unique_ids = data.withColumn('count', F.count('card_id').over(Window.partitionBy('card_id')))
unique_ids.show()

+-------+-----+
|card_id|count|
+-------+-----+
|      1|    4|
|      1|    4|
|      1|    4|
|      1|    4|
|      2|    2|
|      2|    2|
+-------+-----+
```